# How to confirm a user created by Cloudformation AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Ok, I have a CloudFormation template where I create a UserPool and UserPoolUser. Also I have a pre-signup Lambda, because I want to verify my users automatically. Everything works ok, when I register my users through an App, but for those users which I register in CF template in UserPoolUser recources I receive temporary password! What wrong with my template?

```
const handler = async (event) => {
    event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;

    if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
        event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;
    }

    if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty("phone_number")) {
        event.response.autoVerifyPhone = true;
    }

    return event;
};

export { handler };
```

```
"UserPoolUser": {
  "Type": "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUser",
  "Properties": {
    "UserPoolId": { "Ref": "UserPool" },
    "Username": "test@mail.com",
    "UserAttributes": [
       {
        "Name": "email",
        "Value": "test@mail.com"
       },
       {
        "Name": "email_verified",
        "Value": "True"
       },
    ]
  },
  "DependsOn": ["UserPool"]
},
```

Lambda is invoked for `test@mail.com` user, but it is not confirmed(((

I tried to add additional attributes in UserAttributes, but there is no result.